# When we click outside of extension popup window auto close how to keep that on

Tags: google-chrome-extension, refresh

Is there a function that allow me to select text when the extension stays open. Normally when I Use the extension popup and I Click outside the extension the extension close. Is there a wat to avoid this.

Comment: No, not possible. You need to open a new window, use an infobar or perhaps a desktop notification, depending on your use case.

Comment: @Humma Shah  
did you get a method which will prevent the popup to close, unless user have not closed it

Comment: possible duplicate of [avoid chrome popup extension to close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145012/avoid-chrome-popup-extension-to-close)

Answer (score -1):

First Select the portion, then open your extension.
In popup.js use this to get selected content from the page dom

```
document.getSelection().toString()
```

using

```
   $('#addSelected').click(function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{
        //code: 'document.getSelection().toString()'
        file: "getSelectedContent.js"
      },function(r){
      });
});
```

I am also looking for something which will prevent my popup.html to close(on clicking outside the popup window)

Comment: Did you get any solution? is it still persisted ?